# Galerkin Approximation

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

Let $u_N$ be the Galerkin-Approximation of u and $\dim(V_N)=N$. Suppose that the error $\Vert u_N - u \Vert$ can be developed in a power series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}C_i(N^{\alpha})^i$ with $C_i,\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.
I want to derive an approximate calculation of the convergence rate of $\alpha$ under the assumption that $u_N \rightarrow u.$

Unfortunately i don't know how to start. Can someone help please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $~V_N$?

Comment: What is $\alpha$ supposed to converge to?

Comment: 1. $V_N$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $V=H_{0}^{1}$. 
2. i don't know.

Comment: Alright. But you want a "convergence rate of $\alpha$" to what? I assume that $u_N \to u$ is the same as $N \to \infty$ for Galerkin method, which means you have $\alpha <0$, right? But does $\alpha$ depend on $N$? Maybe you just want to determine $\alpha$ if it's a constant?

Comment: i don't know if $\alpha$ depends on $N$. I think the task is to give a approximating method to determine $\alpha$.

Comment: I see. The "of" in your sentence is really confusing. So $\alpha$ is the convergence rate and you need to find it... I think it might depend on the particular equation and the basis you choose. And on $N$ of course, so you would probably want the asymptotic rate for large $N$

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure.
We haven't talked about convergence rate in lecture. 
Can you tell me how to start or the general idea ? 
Sorry for my bad english.